# Swift Block Syntax with Objective-C Function [Venmo-iOS-SDK]

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c-blocks, venmo

I'm currently trying to use the Venmo-iOS-SDK for an application I am working on. The SDK is in objective-C, while I'm trying to use it with a swift app.

I'm having trouble translating the syntax of a completion obj-c block to swift. I found sample code implementing a function I want to use.

```
- (IBAction)logInButtonAction:(id)sender { 
  [[Venmo sharedInstance] requestPermissions:@[VENPermissionMakePayments,
                                             VENPermissionAccessProfile]
                     withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                         if (success) {
                             NSLog("Success")
                         } else {
                             NSLog("Failure")
                     }
 }];
}
```

I've tried doing this

```
@IBAction func loginButtonAction(sender: AnyObject){
    Venmo.sharedInstance().requestPermissions([VENPermissionMakePayments, VENPermissionAccessPhone], withCompletionHandler: { (success: Bool, error: NSErrorPointer) -> Void in
        if success{
            println("Yes")
        }else{
            println("No")
        }
    })
}
```

But get the error

> "Cannot invoke 'requestsPermissions with an argument list of type
>   '([String], withCompletionHandler: (Bool, NSError) -> Void)'

**Is this a problem with how i'm translating the block? Or something else. Looking at the Venmo-SDK the obj-C functions are defined like this**

```
- (void)requestPermissions:(NSArray *)permissions withCompletionHandler:(VENOAuthCompletionHandler)handler;
```

and

```
- (void)requestPermissions:(NSArray *)permissions withCompletionHandler:(VENOAuthCompletionHandler)handler;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it like this (note the lack of types on the completion handler params):

```
@IBAction func loginButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    Venmo.sharedInstance().requestPermissions([VENPermissionMakePayments, VENPermissionAccessPhone], withCompletionHandler: { (success, error) -> Void in
        // code here
    })
}
```

A bit more concise with Swift 2 syntax would be omitting the `-> Void` and explicit `withCompletionHandler:` parameter:

```
@IBAction func loginButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    Venmo.sharedInstance().requestPermissions([VENPermissionMakePayments, VENPermissionAccessPhone]) { (success, error) in
        // code here
    }
}
```

You'll also want to make sure you change your `println` statements to `print`.